# How the unit test for the void method should look like?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I wrote the program that simulates the basket in the shop. The user is able to add and remove items from the basket. Now, I am wondering, how the unit test for my (void) methods should look like. I am using the JUnit 4.

I have tried to change my `addItem` method to return the boolean type, instead of returning nothing. With that I am able to write simple `Assert.assertTrue(basket.add...)`. But I do not know, how the unit test for the void method should be written.

```
public boolean addItem(Item item) {
    if (orderedItems.containsKey(item)) {
        Integer currItemCount = orderedItems.get(item);
        orderedItems.replace(item, currItemCount, currItemCount + 1);
        return true;
    } else {
        orderedItems.put(item, 1);
        return true;
    }
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
    if (orderedItems.containsKey(item)) {
        Integer currItemCount = orderedItems.get(item);
        orderedItems.replace(item, currItemCount, currItemCount + 1);
    } else {
        orderedItems.put(item, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's hard to tell without seeing your whole class, but can you just do `basket.addItem(...);` and then on a separate line, test the condition you expected to change, `Assert.assertEquals(basket.size(), someNewQuantityYouExpected)` and/or `Assert.assertTrue(basket.contains(newItemYouAdded));` etc.

Comment: How the orderedItems map is created, while testing? It depends on how orderedItems is created. You can verify/assert the values in orderedItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the boolean is helpless in your first version since it always return `true`.  Besides, adding a boolean will really not help you to unit test your code since that is too shallow. 
So you should stick to your original idea (without boolean).

About your question : yes the `addItem()` method does not return anything but if you can add items in the basket, you very probably want to read them too.
The simplest way of testing `add()` is relying on a `get()/find()` method.
And reversely.

You could write something like that for a test with a item not present in the basket :

```
@Test
public void addItem_given_item_not_present_then_getAll_retrieves_it() {
   basket.addItem(new Item("foo"));
   Map<Item, Integer> items = basket.getAll();
   // assert items contains 1 element with 1 occurrence and with the foo name
}
```

And you should of course write other test scenarios.